# Tan inverse variation

Tags: trigonometry, matlab

In Matlab when obtaining the inverse tangent of $-\pi$ in radians, the results vary between small changes in decimal points:

> > atan2(sin(-3.141592653589793), cos(-3.141592653589793)) = -3.141592653589793
> >
> > atan2(sin(-3.141593), cos(-3.141593)) = 3.141592307179587
> >
> > atan2(sin(-3.14159), cos(-3.14159)) = -3.141590000000000
> >
> > atan2(sin(-3.1416), cos(-3.1416)) = 3.141585307179587

Could anyone please explain why the sign change occurs between -3.14 and +3.14 ?

Comment: Note the plot of the discontinuity here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/atan2.html

Comment: @Chris Culter Very good reference, though it is maybe difficult to grasp unless one has a minimum culture in complex function theory.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varepsilon$ be very small number, such that $\varepsilon$ > 0

We know that

tan($\frac{\pi}{2}$ + $\varepsilon$) = -$\infty$

tan($\frac{\pi}{2}$ - $\varepsilon$) = +$\infty$

I hope you know why sign change occurs here.

Use similar analogy

Now coming to your question, this happens because range of atan2 is [-${\pi}$,${\pi}$]

So even the slightest change at boundary causes its value to wrap around, reach the other end and continue from there.

Comment: Please use Latex.

Comment: Here’s the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) that will show you how